# Running Gazebo on a Server in ROS

Tags: ros, gazebo, server

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Can the ROS version of Gazebo be split so it's server functions (gzserver) be run on a server in the same way as the full version of Gazebo can?

Is this possible?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/49356/running-gazebo-on-a-server-in-ros/) by [PeterMilani](https://answers.ros.org/users/3621/petermilani/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1493 on 2012-11-28

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Since `gzserver` is just a normal ROS node, it can run on one machine (e.g. a headless server), and you can have other nodes running on a different machine (e.g. your desktop PC). [This tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/MultipleMachines) explains how to do it.

There are some caveats, though:

- You must have full network connectivity between both machines; no firewalls, blocked ports or NAT between them. You can get around that by setting up a VPN, but that's not trivial.
- You should pay attention to the bandwidth of the topics exchanged between nodes running on the two different machines. If you're simulating a Kinect or a stereo camera in Gazebo on your server and subscribe to it (for example, using RViz) on your desktop machine, you're probably going to create more traffic than most "home ISP" connections can handle. You can get around this by grouping nodes which exchange a lot of data together on the same machine.

Oh, and of course the Gazebo GUI is a separate node from the Gazebo server, so all of the above applies.

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2012-11-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [SL Remy](https://answers.ros.org/users/1001/sl-remy/) on 2012-11-29**:
don't forget to set the GAZEBO_MASTER_URI environment variable to something reasonable as well..

**Comment by [PeterMilani](https://answers.ros.org/users/3621/petermilani/) on 2012-11-29**:
Thanks, I was having problems running gzserver directly from the command line? I'm a bit new to the IT world, so what OS should the server be running, is ubuntu fine? Have you got any good links to setting up the environment? Are there any particular modifications required in the launch file?

**Comment by [SL Remy](https://answers.ros.org/users/1001/sl-remy/) on 2012-12-02**:\

1. Ubuntu is fine 2) There are many ways to set up environment variables.. that's a more general unix question (to the googles!). You can check http://ros.org/wiki/roslaunch/XML/env for how to do so from a launch file. Good luck.